# Find out remaining distance before utilizing SetPath()

Tags: path-finding

I am currently trying to find out the remaining distance of an object to the target point where I click at. However, `CalculatePath()` will only have a remaining distance of 0, if I do not use `SetPath()` beforehand. Is there an easy way to get the remaining distance without actually setting an object on their path/in motion?

```
 public void CreatePathing()
{
    ActiveToken = true;

    Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;



    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && ActiveToken == true)
    {
        NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();
        NavMesh.CalculatePath(this.gameObject.transform.position, hit.point, NavMesh.AllAreas, path);     



        if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete && ActiveToken == true )
        {


            if (agent.remainingDistance > this.gameObject.GetComponent<Stats>().speed)
            {

                agent.ResetPath();
            }
            else
            {
                agent.SetPath(path);
                FalsePath = false;
            }

        }

        ActiveToken = false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you need the distance along the travel path, or the beeline distance, ignoring obstacles? If you need the path distance, then you'll need the path first to measure it.